How to connect to Oracle 8i using Java
How do you connect to an Oracle 8i db from a Java/SpringBoot Application?
Which ojdbc jar file should I use? I have tried using:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc8 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>


but it did not connect and I got the below error:
Failed to initialize pool: Index 7 out of bounds for length 2
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Index 7 out of bounds for length 2

Apart from this can we do batch insert in Oracle 8i? If yes then how to do?

Are you really using Oracle 8i database? It reached end-of-life more than twenty years ago. What Java version are you using?

Which Spring Boot and Java version are you using. The ojdbc8 jar is for Java 8 to 11 compatiblity. Assuming you are on something newer you will need the ojdbc11 and use some newer version like the 23.x that is currently available.

Hi @M.Deinum I am using Java 8 and Spring Boot 2.7.3

at least use a newer version then 12.2.0.1 which is ancient.

latest did not work so i tried to use older version.

ok I got second answer also. Yes batch insertion is possible using JdbcTemplate's batchUpdate method.

As per this, the recommended JDBC driver is ojdbc14.jar for Java 1.4 or newer, so download and include it in your project manually or through your pom.xml if you have access to a compatible repository.
It may not be available directly in Maven Central, so you may need to install it in your local Maven Repository manually:
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path/to/ojdbc14.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar

And in your pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>


hello, I tried using ojdbc14 but i get java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract boolean isValid(int)' of interface java.sql.Connection.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkValidationSupport(PoolBase.java:464) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]

HikariCP is calling isValid(int) to check the connection’s validity, which the old ojdbc14 driver doesn’t support because isValid(int) method didn’t exist in Java 1.4.
Try bypassing this by configuring HikariCP to use a custom query for testing connections by adding this to you application.properties (or application.yml if using YAML):
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
This will avoid the isValid(int) method and use an older approach to test connections, compatible with Oracle 8i.

That answer is 13 years old and newer versions are available. So that answer doesn't really apply anymore.

Thanks this worked @Superman You're a genius

@Superman is batch insert possible?

ok I got this answer also. Yes batch insertion is possible using JdbcTemplate's batchUpdate method.

Thanks @AlokKumar. And sorry I couldn't focus on your second question, it just passed by somehow from my eyes, lol.

Hi @Superman so I have around 500,000 rows to get from oracle db- table1 and do something say to write in a diff table. Now if I do something like select userid,salary from table1 offset ? rows fetch next ? rows only. I have kept next ? rows to 1000. I observe it to be slow. like for 1000 it takes 5 sec and for 3000, 15 sec. What can be done to optimise that I fetch 1000 data in chunks from table1

@AlokKumar Try using PARALLE or BULK COLLECT and FORALL for large datasets like you are saying.
